# Conflict between amsmath and ntheorem, or, how I fell into an infinite troubleshooting loop

Tags: amsmath, incompatibility, ntheorem

There are similar questions on this site, but nothing quite fixed this problem for me.

When using `amsmath` with `ntheorem` I get either a missing end of theorem symbol (when my theorem ends with an equation) or my cross-referencing gets screwed up.

Here is a minimal example of the missing end of theorem mark:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}
\theoremsymbol{*}
\newtheorem{myDefinition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{myDefinition}
    I don't get my end of definition mark \ldots
    \begin{equation}
        x=y
        \label{test}
    \end{equation}
\end{myDefinition}

\ldots but the equation cross-reference works: \eqref{test}.

\end{document}
```

Here is a minimal example of the screwed-up cross-referencing (the argument `amsmath` has been omitted from the `ntheorem` package call):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\theoremsymbol{*}
\newtheorem{myDefinition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{myDefinition}
    Now I get my end of definition mark \ldots
    \begin{equation}
        x=y
        \label{test}
    \end{equation}
\end{myDefinition}

\ldots but the equation cross-reference fails: \eqref{test}.

\end{document}
```

I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: When I run your first MWE on my machine (MacTeX2012, MacOSX 10.7.5), I do get an endmark, *below* the equation number.

Comment: I think it's bad style to use end marks along with equation numbers on the right: the mark is fighting against the number and loses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can verify your problem on an up-to-date TL 2012. I agree with @egreg that it doesn't look great, but if you'd like to stick to your guns, then you can use an `\mbox{}` to make things 'work'.

[image]

This trick also works when using the `mdframed` package with a `frame` that ends with an `equation`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}
\theoremsymbol{*}
\newtheorem{myDefinition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{myDefinition}
    I don't get my end of definition mark \ldots
    \begin{equation}
        x=y
        \label{test}
    \end{equation}
    \mbox{}
\end{myDefinition}
\ldots but the equation cross-reference works: \eqref{test}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this used to work in earlier versions. Sometimes it help using the `empheq` package with no emphasizing, some of the extra options for `empheq` *fix* some placement problems in `ntheorem`

Comment: @daleif my distribution is completely up to date- did you mean that *your* method worked on earlier versions?

Comment: In earlier versions. Now a days I just use `empheq`, I'll post an example as an answer.

Comment: I confirm the workaround and appreciate the confirmation.  I might try to submit a bug report.

Comment: @StephenMcAteer you're welcome- I don't know if I'd call it a bug, but of course you can see what the maintainers say :)

Answer (score 2):

This works

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ntheorem]{empheq}
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}
\theoremsymbol{*}
\newtheorem{myDefinition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{myDefinition}
I don't get my end of definition mark \ldots
\begin{empheq}{equation}
x=y
\label{test}
\end{empheq}
\end{myDefinition}
\ldots but the equation cross-reference works: \eqref{test}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: That code produces the theoremmark overlapping the equation number and the cross-refernce does not work.

Comment: This used to work. I've just tested with the `ntheorem` version from 2005 (v1.25) and then it works and the marker is placed correctly. And that `ntheorem` can actually place the marker correctly by itself! I'll send an email to Wolfgang May

Answer (score 2):

Please try the examples with the ["development" version 1.33 of `ntheorem`](http://user.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/~may/Ntheorem/).

This version, although by now more than 1 year old is still a bit unstable an not sufficiently tested since I changed major things in the handling of skips - so please check the skips in your documents.